# The "deleted:1" operator in search does not work well for Teams posts

Tags: bug, search, deleted-questions, stack-overflow-for-teams

When [searching for deleted questions I posted](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3Ame+is%3Aq+deleted%3A1) with the query `user:me is:q deleted:1`, the `deleted:1` part is respected for content on the main site, but I get *all* my questions (not just deleted ones) from my Teams accounts:

[image]

Comment: Where is `deleted:1` documented? I didn't see it when I looked at the advanced tips on Teams.

Comment: @Laurel [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) – I'm not using it on Teams, just on the main SO site. By default, search includes results from my Teams.

Comment: But is it supported in Teams at all? If it's not then it should either be supported (why not give it to everyone in a team?) or not show Teams results at all.

Comment: AFAIK it isn't. I'm fine with either option.

Comment: Same here - but it's not just for questions. A plain "deleted:1" search will show Qs from Teams and then answers from my main account.